# Conditional Operator not working as expected in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, conditional-statements

Below conditional operator is not working as expected
I have included the conditions in scenario based.

If no src or tar matches, should be rate=0

If src is present in `arr` and is `SGD` and src is present in `arr` and is `SGD` (vice-versa), rate be 0.4

If src is present in `arr` and is `"EUR" || "GBP" || "USD"` and tar is present in `arr` and is `"SGD"`,(vice-versa), rate be 0.3

If src is present in `arr` and tar is present in `arr` rate should be 0.5

scenario:

```
(src==="SGD" and tar==="AUD") or (src==="AUD" && tar==="SGD")  => rate="0.4"
src === "SGD") and (tar === "EUR" or "GBP" or "USD") => rate=0.3
(src==`arr` values  and tar==`arr` values)=> rate=0.5 
(src no match arr && tar no match arr)=> rate=0
```

```
var arr =["AED","BGN","CAD","CHF","CZK","DKK","HKD","HUF","ILS","INR",
       "JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","QAR","RON","SAR","SEK","THB","TRY","ZAR"];

I tried , but not working if src="SGD" and tar="CNY" it should rate =0
var res=
      ((src === "SGD" && tar === "AUD") || (src  === "AUD" && tar === "SGD"))?
      rate = 0.4 : 
      ((src === "SGD" && (tar === "EUR" || "GBP" || "USD")) ||
      ((src === "EUR" || "GBP" || "USD") && tar === "SGD"))?
      rate = 0.3:
      (src.indexOf(arr)!=-1 && tar.indexOf(arr)!=-1) ?
      rate = 0.5 : 
     rate=0;
```

Comment: That's not the correct way to write a condition: `(tar === "EUR" || "GBP" || "USD"))`. This will always evaluate to true.

Comment: You don't need to nest assignments within the ternary operands. You could do `var res = cond ? 0.4 : so on`

Answer (score 1):

You used you or condition without checking with a variable. just like `"USD" || "GBP"` which will return `true` always.

and you have another error you should check like `array.index(variable)`. but you checked like

```
src.indexOf(arr)!=-1 && tar.indexOf(arr)!=-1
```

I have added a demo snippet please check it.

I used that particular condition like.

```
(tar === "EUR" || tar === "GBP" || tar === "USD"))
```

```js
var tar = "DKK";
var src = "AUD";
var arr =["AUD","DKK","AED","BGN","CAD","CHF","CZK","DKK","HKD","HUF","ILS","INR",
       "JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","QAR","RON","SAR","SEK","THB","TRY","ZAR"];
var res=
      ((src === "SGD" && tar === "AUD") || (src  === "AUD" && tar === "SGD"))?
      rate = 0.4 : 
      ((src === "SGD" && (tar === "EUR" || tar === "GBP" || tar === "USD")) ||
      ((src === "EUR" || "GBP" || "USD") && tar === "SGD"))?
      rate = 0.3:
      (arr.indexOf(src)!=-1 && arr.indexOf(tar)!=-1) ?
      rate = 0.5 : 
     rate=0;
     
     console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks but if src="AUD" && tar "DKK" should be 0.5, but returns 0.

Comment: code is correct sorry, "AUD" was not present in arr thats y returns 0

Comment: and you have another error you should chck like `array.index(variable)`. but ypu are doing the opposite. updated my answer with tat too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `tar ===` for every condition:

```
(tar === "EUR" || tar === "GBP" || tar === "USD")
```

Alternatively, use `includes`:

```
(["EUR", "GBP", "USD"].includes(tar))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function which returns a value early, if a condition match

```
function check() {
    const group = ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"];
    if (src === "SGD" && tar === "AUD" || src === "AUD" && tar === "SGD") return 0.4;
    if (src === "SGD" && group.includes(tar) || group.includes(src) && tar === "SGD") return 0.3;
    if (arr.includes(src) && arr.includes(tar)) return 0.5;
    return 0;
}
```

In short

```
var rate = src === "SGD" && tar === "AUD" || src === "AUD" && tar === "SGD"
        ? 0.4
        : src === "SGD" && ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"].includes(tar) || ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"].includes(src) && tar === "SGD"
            ? 0.3
            : arr.includes(src) && arr.includes(tar)
                ? 0.5
                : 0;
```

Comment: thanks but if src="AUD" && tar "DKK" should be 0.5, but returns 0.

Comment: that's right, there is no condition for `'DKK'` in the given code.

Comment: thanks , code is correct sorry, "AUD" was not present in arr thats y returns 0